# Export data excel ws to .txt with same number columns with equal length and break per column to adjust to the required layout of the import software?

Tags: excel, export, break, txt

How can I export this data to have the same length and paste in a **.txt** with the same columns and breaks ?

[Original xlsx or .csv data image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3Vwz.png)

[Wanted output .txt Notepad++ data fields Opt.1:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIrdJ.png)

[Wanted output .txt Notepad equal to Notepad++ data fields Opt.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSfs7.png)

Excel ws Module VBA I have not working like intended:

```
Sub GravarArquivoTXT()
Dim fileNum As Long
Dim i As Long

fileNum = FreeFile
Open ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\NISSAN_ENC_UPLOAD.txt" For Output As fileNum

With Sheets("Output")
    i = 1
    Do While .Cells(i, "A").Text <> ""
        Print #fileNum, .Cells(i, "A").Text & "" & _
                  .Cells(i, "B").Text & "" & _
                  .Cells(i, "C").Text & "" & _
                  .Cells(i, "D").Text & "" & _
                  .Cells(i, "E").Text & "" & _
                  .Cells(i, "F").Text
        i = i + 1
    Loop
End With
Close fileNum

MsgBox "Arquivo gerado com sucesso!", vbInformation, "OK"

Sheets("Autoline Controlo Compras").Activate
End Sub
```

But the output .txt actual is this with the above code:

[actual output (wrong) without break/column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ic3Ql.png)

Can someone help?

Thanks!

Comment: Rather than change the output, change the distance of the tabs in the text editor

Comment: How can i do that?